# Intellij Run config input file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there anyway to set up an IntelliJ run config for a Java program, so that it runs as if I ran this in terminal:

```
java Uguu < file
```

How would I tell IntelliJ to put the `<` file part?

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ IDEA's run configurations do not support input redirection. Please consider modifying your program so that it can accept a file name as a command line parameter and read from that file, instead of reading from the standard input.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Run -> Edit Configurations... -> Tab "Configuration" -> Program arguments`

Comment: I have tried setting < file as the program argument, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to simulate input of file:

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream("FILE_NAME"));
```

Or send file name as parameter and then put it into FileInputStream:

```
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
```